# Rename pdf files from recursive numeric strings into original name from same .html (http link) or .txt file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I download some pdf files from [HERE](https://arxiv.org/list/quant-ph/1610?skip=0&show=25)

Pdf files are downloaded not using original filenames but by number strings like

```
1610.00005
1610.00022
```

Fortunally in this HTTP link page or txt files (if I copy for offline renaming) I have relative 
`numeric -> original text filename` 

string corrispondence

For example when I download this files

```
- A Note on Time Operators in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics
- A Stronger Theorem Against Macro-realism
- Determining quantum correlations in bipartite systems - from qubit to qutrit and beyond
- Pair entanglement in dimerized spin-s chains
```

Files are downloaded with this filenames

```
1610.00005.pdf
1610.00022.pdf
1610.00041.pdf
1610.00056.pdf
```

BUT I want rename into original filesname not in a number string
I'd like to set a http link or text file for path

I have only this codes 
(*powershell*)

```
$names = Get-Content c\myfiles
Get-ChildItem C:\somedir\*.pdf | Sort -desc | 
    Foreach {$i=0} {Rename-Item $_ ($_.basename + $names[$i++] + $_.extension) -WhatIf}
```

or *batch code*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the list of authors:
set i=0
for /F %%a in (myfiles.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "author[!i!]=%%a"
)

rem Do the rename:
set i=0
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do ren "%%a" "%%~Na!author[%%i]!%%~Xa"
)
```

Comment: What is the exact content of `myfiles.txt`? is it only the new PDF file names, or are the related numeric names also stated there?

Comment: inside myfiles.txt is like this http://pastebin.com/RKVt5WNG

Comment: Add the content of `myfiles.txt` to to question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40370636/edit) your post! Links are bad as they might become invalid in future, and some users might not have sufficient privileges to access some external resources. In addition, you want help, so you should make it as easy as possible for other users to help you; you will likely receive more answers then; otherwise, if users have to collect all necessary information on their own, they might perhaps skip to the next question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#All PDFs | Rename { query Arxiv for the abstract by filename, use the page title + ".pdf"}

Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $title = (Invoke-WebRequest "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)").parsedhtml.title
    $title = $title -replace '[\\/:\*\?"<>\|]', '-'       # replace forbidden characters
    "$title.pdf"                                          # in filenames with -
}
```

You might want to put a `-whatif` on the end first, to see what it would do, in case it ruins all the filenames. Or take a backup copy of the folder.

Edit: One of the titles is "Signatures of bifurcation on quantum correlations: Case of quantum kicked top" and the `:` is not allowed in a filename. Script edited to replace all forbidden characters in Windows filenames with dashes instead.

Comment: mmm.. but what link do you use ? link give me error. I use this command `gci *.pdf | ren -N {(iwr "https://arxiv.org/list/quant-ph/1610?skip=0&show=50$($_.BaseName)").parsedhtml.title + ".pdf"}` it flush something from site but then i receive this error http://i.imgur.com/fIjXrfe.png. BaseName I believe is set to like *arXiv:1610.00005* and not to nametext present in http relative link because file is downloaded like *1610.0000* or *1610.0000.pdf*

Comment: mm.. look DOM from your relative URL `<h1 class="title mathjax"><span class="descriptor">Title:</span>
A Note on Time Operators in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics</h1> ` maybe you need to extract TITLE name from `<h1 class="title mathjax">` tag if you want use your `https://arxiv.org/abs/$`

Comment: I use the URL in my answer, and it works fine, look: http://i.imgur.com/1gdp7qg.png Why are you changing the URL to one which doesn't work?

Comment: lol, I see now - i don't used Windows Powershell ISE but simply version, great, thanks. But, is possibile to add near to filename also Authors names also ? Some characters are not admitted like `?` `:` and is not permit  bypass `Max characters` for filename. Can you add please also this ?

Comment: P.S: for some files you can't rename like **1610.00124.pdf** or **1610.00336.pdf** because it tell me `ren: Unable to rename the specified destination because it is a path or a name
of device.In line:1 car:13
+ gci *.pdf | ren -N {(iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)").parsedhtml.titl ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand`

Comment: @user3520363 Ah, characters in the title which are not allowed in filenames. I have edited my answer to handle that. (If you run it again, it will error for all the files with correct names now, hopefully that's not significant).

Comment: Deart Tasselating - can you help me with this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526234/order-files-by-subjects-category-and-move-them-into-relative-folders-from-http-l ?